# Bonjour with NWListener & NWBrowser p2p connections

Tags: ios, bonjour, network-framework

I am using Bonjour to advertise and discover devices that are near to one another. I am successfully starting my NWListener

```
 let parameters = NWParameters(tls: nil, tcp: tcpOptions)
                        parameters.includePeerToPeer = true
                        
                        let listener = try NWListener(using: parameters)
default 12:42:30.601650-0400    MDNS Listener starting
default 12:42:30.603393-0400    MDNS Listener state changed ready
default 12:42:30.603482-0400    MDNS Listener ready on Optional(64754)
```

When both devices are on the same network, the client finds the service and connects without issues. When I put one device on my guest network or take both off of WiFi in hope they discover over Bluetooth they are no longer discoverable. I assumed using `includesPeerToPeer=true` that networks wouldn't matter.

Im unable to find good resources about this topic, does anyone have any insight?

For reference my NWBrowser prints out

```
default 12:44:19.245018-0400    MDNS Start Browsing for type _myservice._tcp    PacketTunnel
default 12:44:19.254797-0400    MDNS Browser updated ready
default 12:44:19.254972-0400    MDNS Browser ready []
```

Comment: I'm definitely no expert on this and am just learning it myself, but I am able to have an NWListener advertise itself and an NWBrowser discover it when I'm away from wifi. I don't have wifi turned off, but they are off the wifi network. I believe it's using adhoc wifi between the 2 devices to connect directly (ie, peer-to-peer). I haven't been able to get Network framework to use Bluetooth at all.

Comment: Acc to [this answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/104061) by Eskimo: "as of iOS 11 we no longer support peer-to-peer networking over Bluetooth; it’s peer-to-peer Wi-Fi only these days."